# Black Border appearing in button in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have added a button in my HTML and tried to add this background color #F5F8FA and its showing me a small black border for no reason

[button with black border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0u07.png)

> Thank you so much for your help in advance

**HTML:**

```
        <div class="slider-container">
            <div class="slider">
                <div class="slide">
                    <button class="slider-button">
                        <p class="textbutton">全部</p></button>
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <button class="slider-button">特色街区</button>
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <button class="slider-button">红色印记</button>
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <button class="slider-button">文博场馆</button>
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <button class="slider-button">探店寻访</button>
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <button class="slider-button">xxxx类</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.slider-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

.slider-container {
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15rpx;
}

.slider {
    display: flex;
}

.slide {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    margin-right: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.slide:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}

.slider-button {
    background-color: #F5F8FA;
    width: auto;
    height: 75rpx;
    border-radius: 50rpx;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    color: black;
    
    
}
```

No need to worry about "rpx" that is just something we use in uni-app

Answer (score 1):

One of the browser's default stylings is to add a border to `<button>` elements. It's nothing special—you can get rid of it by just adding adding `border: none` to your `.slider-button` style rule.

```
.slider-button {
    border: none;
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: I wish it was that simple I already tried that :/